# in Karate the surefire XML report created appends and merges test steps for all examples one after another in next test executed

Tags: karate

I am running following scenario example:

```
Scenario Outline: Basic test for user <userID>
When url 'xyz'
And path 'abc/efg'
And params id = <userID>
When method get
Then status 200

Example:
|userID|
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|
```

Note: I am passing **userID** from examples to **scenario name** and also params
now after this is executed the xml report generated in surefire for above test looks something like this:

```
<testSuite failures="0"
name="xyz.feature"
tests="4"
time="8.5">
<testcase classname="xyz"
name="Basic test for user 1"
time="1.20"
<system-out>
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '1'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
</system-out>
</testcase>

<testcase classname="xyz"
name="Basic test for user 2"
time="2.10"
<system-out>
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '1'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '2'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
</system-out>
</testcase>

<testcase classname="xyz"
name="Basic test for user 3"
time="3.21"
<system-out>
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '1'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '2'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '3'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
</system-out>
</testcase>

<testcase classname="xyz"
name="Basic test for user 4"
time="3.56"
<system-out>
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '1'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '2'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '3'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
When url 'xyz' ...................passed
And path 'abc/efg'................passed
And params id = '4'...............passed
When method get...................passed
Then status 200...................passed
</system-out>
</testcase>
```

Please see how for first test case with user id 1 there are 4 steps printed as passed which is correct. Now for second test case the steps of first test case are appended to steps of second testcase. For 3rd testcase steps of testcase1 and testcase2 are shown along with testcase3 steps.This creates an issue in CI pipelines. Ideally in xml report all tescase should have only 4 steps but that is not the case.

Wanted to check on what could be the issue here.
I am using parallel runner as:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java

Logback file as : https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/examples/jobserver/src/test/java/logback-test.xml

let me know if any more details required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a bug. Most teams use the Cucumber JSON output to generate HTML reports. Also in 0.9.6 onwards Karate has built-in HTML reports: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1237797240686522369

Please follow these instructions and submit an issue, keep it simple: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have Raised an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1282